How are source ports chosen for iptables SNAT targets?
By default the SNAT target keeps the source port of the original packet. If that port is already in use, it chooses one at random. Is there any way to influence the choice of this port or gage the range within which it is chosen? In my testing net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range didn't seem to have an influence on this. I'm wondering if there is a different setting for it


By default the SNAT target keeps the source port of the original packet. If that port is already in use, it chooses one at random.

It's not chosen at random by default, instead the following is the default algorithm
(the bold part confirms your statement though about keeping the original port)

If no port range is specified,
then source ports below 512 will be mapped to other ports
below 512: those between 512 and 1023 inclusive will be
mapped to ports below 1024, and other ports will be mapped
to 1024 or above. Where possible, no port alteration will
occur.

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/iptables-extensions.8.html

Is there any way to influence the choice of this port or gage the range within which it is chosen?

Yes it's possible by by using either masquerade or snat statements in your NAT rule by specifying port ranges as follows --to-ports port[-port]

--to-ports port[-port]

          This specifies a range of source ports to use, overriding
          the default SNAT source port selection heuristics (see
          above). This is only valid if the rule also specifies one
          of the following protocols: tcp, udp, dccp or sctp.

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/iptables-extensions.8.html

In my testing net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range didn't seem to have an influence on this.

The net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range applies to listener ports that must be available to be listened to, it has nothing to do with SNAT, that is, those ports will never be used by NAT in fact.
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/filenet-p8-platform/5.5.x?topic=listener-linux
